# Why StrCmp function does not work in HP QTP

Tags: qtp

QTP supports VBScript, but when I use the string comparison function StrCmp in my test case to compare two strings, I always get a Type mismatch error. Why? Even the following simple code can't run!

```
StrCmp "abc", "def"
```

This line of code also get the Type Mismatch error as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's meant to be `StrComp` (with an `o`)?

And, it's a function so you should probably treat it as such:

```
If StrComp(s1, s2) = 0 Then
```